# Figuring out dependencies of a python package

Tags: python

Is there a way for figuring out the dependencies of a python package without installing it?

Currently I can do that by using the following two commands:

```
pip install <package>
pip show <package>
```

The last command lists out dependencies with some other metadata.

cheers